# WooCommerce product main images are blurry but not in lightbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

my single product images are blurred when I call up the lightbox, but the respective image is sharp again. I have uploaded the images in a format of 800 x 800px and have also tried the format 1500 x 1500px. Unfortunately, nothing has changed. I have also adjusted the image size settings according to the WooCommerce guide and unfortunately nothing has changed. I also changed the setting of crop thumbnails from 1:1 to uncropped. Nothing has changed here either.

What surprises me the most is that the single product images are displayed blurred but as soon as I call up the lightbox it is displayed sharply.

I have uploaded the images in a format of 800 x 800px and have also tried the format 1500 x 1500px.

Any help would be highly appreciated.